# Multisite with Codeigniter 3 | Database auto switch

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello guys I need some help with multisite using Codeigniter.

So I was developing a multisite system where different companies register and they are given their sub-domain (E.g Company `ABC` go to `www.system.com` and register, then they are given sub-domain `abc.system.com`) then database `abc` (encrypted) is generated and default tables are created by the system.

All companies use the same interface, so the only thing change is the database.

My ideas was every time someone access `abc.system.com` I explode (abc.system.com) and I take `abc` encrypt it and I change DB connection in the `config/database.php` to

```
$db['company'] = array(
'database' => 'encrypted(abc)',
```

And User will use `$this->db->query`

But now when am thinking about it, disaster will happen when someone else happen to login to `xyz.system.com` because connection will change again to `encrypted(xyz)` because he/she will also be using `$this->db->query`

Remember the system is one and only database are changing.

I did not understand the technique of multisite using `.htaccess`

Now am stuck guys any ideas on how I can go around it?
Am using codeigniter 3.

Comment: Does your www.system.com has completely different behaviour then all others dynamic created abc.system.com / xyz...

Comment: Yes, `www.system.com` is the home/landing domain were user register their companies, while `abc.system.com` is the system which serve` abc` company @Svetlio

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to init this 2nd "company" DB inside a MY_Controller class which you can extend in all your Controllers (perhaps only those which are companies related.

By CI default configurations you are able to create MY_Conroller inside the core folder which will extend CI_Controller and any controller inside your controllers can extend it.

Inside this MY_Controller you will be able to parse the host (domain) and to set the right DB.. 
Example :

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $dbC;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        //HERE YOU CAN MAKE THE 2nd DB load after you detect that you are in valid subdomain
        $expHost = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
        if( count($expHost) === 3 && $expHost !== 'www') {
            $dbC_config = // Get your DB COMPANY configurations or input it here as array..
            $dbC_config['database'] = 'encrypted('.$expHost[0].')';
            $this->dbC = $this->load->database($dbC_config);
        }
    }
}
```